# Fundamental Period of $\tan x \cot x$

Tags: functions, periodic-functions

What is the period of $\tan x \cot x?$ I was given this question today. What I did was simplify the expression , and it reduced to a constant function. So it had no fundamental period.

But my teacher told me that the answer was $\frac{\pi}{2}$. How is it so?

Comment: The function is constant on its domain, but the domain has “holes” at $k\pi/2$, for $k$ an integer.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x) = \dfrac{\tan x}{\tan x}\neq 1$$
$$f(x) = 1, x\neq k\dfrac{\pi}{2}, k\in\mathbb{I}\\$$

The period is $\pi / 2$, since the function isn't defined for integral multiple of pi/2. So as egreg also mentions, it will have holes in graph.

For a function to be periodic, it must have translational symmetry in its graph.

Answer (score 0):

This is $1$, so it *is* constant.

Are you sure that you have the right problem?

Might the problem be
$\tan(\cot(x))$?

Comment: OP does have the right problem. The function is not constant everywhere, it is undefined at points $x=n\frac\pi 2$ where $n\in\Bbb Z$

Comment: no the problem is $\tan x \cot x$ only.

Answer (score 0):

A function $f : A \to B$ is periodic with period $p$ if, for all $x \in A$, $$f(x + p) = f(x)$$ and $p$ is the least such value for which this is true.  For $$f(x) = \tan x \cot x,$$ we see that $f$ is well-defined on the domain $$A = \{x \in \mathbb R : 2x/\pi \not\in \mathbb Z\},$$ that is to say, all reals which are not integer multiples of $\pi/2$.  On this domain, we can state $f(x) = 1$:  another way to put it is, $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & x \in A \\ \text{undefined}, & x \not\in A. \end{cases}$$  Now suppose that $0 < p < \pi/2$.  Then we would have $f(x+p) = 1 = f(x)$ whenever $x \in A$ and $x+p \in A$.  But if $x+p \not\in A$ while $x \in A$, we would have a violation of the periodicity condition.  Yet a situation arises for $x = \pi/2 - p$:  since by construction $0 < p < \pi/2$, $x = \pi/2 - p \in A$, yet $x + p = \pi/2 \not \in A$.  Consequently, $f$ cannot be periodic with $p < \pi/2$.

It is rather straightforward to continue to reason that $f$ **is** periodic with $p = \pi/2$.  For example, suppose $x \not\in A$; then $2x/\pi \in \mathbb Z$.  Then $$\frac{2(x+\pi/2)}{\pi} = \frac{2x}{\pi} + 1 \in \mathbb Z,$$ consequently $x+\pi/2 \not\in A$.  And since each step is reversible, we conclude $x + \pi/2 \not\in A$ implies $x \not \in A$; hence $x \in A$ if and only if $x + \pi/2 \in A$.  Then apply the period condition to conclude $f(x+\pi/2) = 1 = f(x)$ for all $x \in A$.

Comment: didn't get what you wrote at all, why would you suppose 0<p<π/2.??? I get that tan(pi/2) is defined???? Ok, fine. If you just need to avoid pi/2 just say so, why does it have to be between 0 and pi/2???  Then we would have f(x+p)=1 ??? why???? don't get. "x=π/2−p" where does this come from??...